# MySQL 3 column query return duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

```
x_Id  | y_Id | z_Id
----- |----- |-----
1     | 1    | 1
2     | 1    | 1
3     | 1    | 1
4     | 1    | 1
5     | 1    | 1
1     | 2    | 3
```

I am relatively new at programming and I cant figure out this MySql query. I need to select x_Id only where ((y_Id = 1 AND z_Id = 1) AND (y_Id = 2 AND z_Id = 3)).
Therefore, using these numbers as an example the only thing that should be selected is (x_Id =) 1.

**All of these columns are in the same table

The closest I have come is by using this query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `relationships` 
WHERE
    y_id = 1 AND
    z_id = 1

UNION    
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `relationships` 
WHERE
    z_id = 3 AND
    y_id = 2
```

However, this returns all the x_ids and x_id = 1 again as a duplicate.

**I am using sqlPro and MySql 5

Comment: I understand your requirement better now, and have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to Union.

**Updated after seeing comments:**

```
select
*
from relationships T1
INNER JOIN relationshipsT2 on t1.x_Id   = t2.x_Id  where
((T1.y_Id = 1 AND T1.z_Id = 1) AND (T2.y_Id  = 2 AND T2.zz_Id= 3))
```

also you can only return `x_Id`  instead of `*`

Comment: the `Distinct` will avoid repeated values

Comment: This still returns all x_ids where y = 1 AND z= 1. Due to the "OR" I believe. If I swap that "OR" with a AND I get no results because no row contains both the conditions.

Comment: but.. in your question you said that you want all x_ids where y =1 AND  z=1.. of course that you will get that x_id's !

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated after seeing comments:

Using an aggregate `SUM()` you can total up the number of conditions met per value of `x_id`. If the total is > 1, both conditions are met somewhere in the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT x_id FROM (
  SELECT
    x_id,
    SUMCASE WHEN (y_id = 1 AND z_id = 1) OR (z_id = 3 AND y_id = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS hasboth
  FROM relationships
  GROUP BY x_id
  HAVING hasboth > 1
) subq
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the x_id value you can use the query above, but just add DISTINCT and project only the x_id value.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT x_id 
FROM 
 `relationships` 
WHERE
     y_id = 1 AND z_id = 1

UNION

SELECT 
    DISTINCT x_id 
FROM 
    `relationships` 
WHERE
    z_id = 3 AND y_id = 2
```

There are few other way how to do it, which are even easier such as use OR in the WHERE clause.